# Updating of large number of records in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, items

I am thinking about most effectively a way, how to download and updating items to/in my database (MySQL). I am working with tens of thousands to hundreds items.

I have a table (**table_a**), that contains items. Every night I am downloading new data and these data are stored in **table_b**. So - it's midnight, I'll download data to **table_b** and after download all of data I will start to comparing data between **table_b** and **table_a**.
If item in **table_b** exist in **table_a**, so I will edit 3-4 number value in **table_a** by **table_b**. If this item isn't in **table_a**, so this item I will save to **table_a**.

This way I am updating items in my table **table_a** one time of a day. The problem of this method - this procedure is very slow... for ca 20.000 items it takes ca 25-30 minutes. (my app is running on RoR)

I would like to ask you - can you help me, please, better and especially faster way to update new records into the table (**table_a**)?
I will be very grateful for it... thank you in advance,
M.

Comment: Do you do the update from your Ruby application, or have you converted it to an in-database UPDATE statement already?

Comment: I am updating an items from my rails app. Specifically, the first I am calling URL/controlller/download_it and then URL/controller/update_it -> and these two operations are carried out in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the required data is available in the database, the logic is not overwhelmingly complex or subject to frequent changes, and performance is an issue, migrating the logic into a single SQL statement is one of your most obvious options.

Something along the lines of this:

INSERT INTO table_a SELECT * FROM table_b ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value1=table_b.value1, value2=table_b.value2, ....;

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Indexes: These should make lookups faster.
2. Hashes: If you are comparing long strings, it's better to create hashes before storing them in the database and comparing their hashes.

Comment: could you be, please, more specific `Roland`? The comparing is based on integer value AND string value.

Comment: Basically, string comparisons are really costly in mysql. When I built a spider for a project and was saving whole html bodies, comparing the results was very costly.

Comment: Also, the indexes bit refers to indexes for the foreign keys of table_a in table_b.

Comment: I have studied now foreign keys... but I am not sure, if is it what I need (I am sorry, maybe I just don't understand it). Because in my case -- tables `table_a` and `table_b` are totally the same - my first idea, why I did it, was reduction offline time of `table_a` - now the user can searching information from `table_a` and in background is running actualization items in `table_a` (from `table_b`)and insert of new items.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why doing the inserts/updates on table_a directly instead of buffering them in table_b is not an option? Why would it cause offline time?

Comment: Well... I solved similar problem in past, and I deleted items in table and download the new items. The problem was, that the time between deleting old items and inserting new items was ca 5 minutes - and these 5 minutes on the page wasn't the content. No I am trying avoid this situation, so I am downloading data to "temp" table and from this "temp" table I am copy or insert the "fresh" data into my "main" table... I know is not perfect solution, I am searching some better way, how to do...